# Querying DAU/MAU over time (daily)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a daily sessions table with columns user_id and date. I'd like to graph out DAU/MAU (daily active users / monthly active users) on a daily basis. For example:

```
Date         MAU      DAU     DAU/MAU
2014-06-01   20,000   5,000   20%
2014-06-02   21,000   4,000   19%
2014-06-03   20,050   3,050   17%
...          ...      ...     ...
```

Calculating daily active users is straightforward but calculating the monthly active users e.g. the number of users that logged in today minus 30 days, is causing problems. How is this achieved without a left join for each day?

Edit: I'm using Postgres.

Comment: What database are you using, MySQL or Postgres?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming you have values for each day, you can get the total counts using a subquery and `range between`:

```
with dau as (
      select date, count(userid) as dau
      from dailysessions ds
      group by date
     )
select date, dau,
       sum(dau) over (order by date rows between -29 preceding and current row) as mau
from dau;
```

Unfortunately, I think you want distinct users rather than just user counts.  That makes the problem much more difficult, especially because Postgres doesn't support `count(distinct)` as a window function.

I think you have to do some sort of self join for this.  Here is one method:

```
with dau as (
      select date, count(distinct userid) as dau
      from dailysessions ds
      group by date
     )
select date, dau,
       (select count(distinct user_id)
        from dailysessions ds
        where ds.date between date - 29 * interval '1 day' and date
       ) as mau
from dau;
```

Comment: When I run this query for multiple days, the `mau` column in the result set does not change, when it ideally should change as the `mau` should be different for each day. Any pointers as to how this may be fixed?

Comment: @Patthebug . . . Try asking a new question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Here's the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53839230/fix-the-mau-problem-while-calculating-dau-and-mau-on-amazon-redshift

Comment: @GordonLinoff, as usual, very elegant solution, thanks!

Comment: The premise of this solution ignores that MAU is **not** the sum of DAU over a month. Otherwise, if you had the same user every day for a month, your MAU would be 30, when in reality it should be 1.

Comment: How would you get dau/mau from this?

Answer (score 4):

This one uses COUNT DISTINCT to get the rolling 30 days DAU/MAU:

(calculating reddit's user engagement in BigQuery - but the SQL is standard enough to be used on other databases)

```
SELECT day, dau, mau, INTEGER(100*dau/mau) daumau
FROM (
  SELECT day, EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(author) dau, FIRST(mau) mau
  FROM (
    SELECT DATE(SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(created_utc)) day, author
    FROM [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2015_09]
    WHERE subreddit='AskReddit') a
  JOIN (
    SELECT stopday, EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(author) mau
    FROM (SELECT created_utc, subreddit, author FROM [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2015_09], [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2015_08]) a
    CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT DATE(SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(created_utc)) stopday
      FROM [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2015_09]
      GROUP BY 1
    ) b
    WHERE subreddit='AskReddit'
    AND SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(created_utc) BETWEEN DATE_ADD(stopday, -30, 'day') AND TIMESTAMP(stopday)
    GROUP BY 1
  ) b
  ON a.day=b.stopday
  GROUP BY 1
)
ORDER BY 1
```

I went further at [How to calculate DAU/MAU with BigQuery (engagement)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33226570/how-to-calculate-dau-mau-with-bigquery/33226571)

Answer (score 3):

I've written about this on [my blog](http://www.ilkkapeltola.fi/2017/11/calculating-active-users-and-churn.html).

The DAU is easy, as you noticed. You can solve the MAU by first creating a view with boolean values for when a user activates and de-activates, like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "vw_login" AS 
 SELECT *
    , LEAST (LEAD("date") OVER w, "date" + 30) AS "activeExpiry"
    , CASE WHEN LAG("date") OVER w IS NULL THEN true ELSE false AS "activated"
    , CASE
 WHEN LEAD("date") OVER w IS NULL THEN true
 WHEN LEAD("date") OVER w - "date" > 30 THEN true
 ELSE false
 END AS "churned"
    , CASE
 WHEN LAG("date") OVER w IS NULL THEN false
 WHEN "date" - LAG("date") OVER w <= 30 THEN false
 WHEN row_number() OVER w > 1 THEN true
 ELSE false
 END AS "resurrected"
   FROM "login"
   WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY "user_id" ORDER BY "date")
```

This creates boolean values per user per day when they become active, when they churn and when they re-activate.

Then do a daily aggregate of the same:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "vw_activity" AS
SELECT 
    SUM("activated"::int) "activated"
  , SUM("churned"::int) "churned"
  , SUM("resurrected"::int) "resurrected"
  , "date"
  FROM "vw_login"
  GROUP BY "date"
  ;
```

And finally calculate running totals of active MAUs by calculating the cumulative sums over the columns. You need to join the vw_activity twice, since the second one is joined to the day when the user becomes inactive (i.e. 30 days since their last login).

I've included a date series in order to ensure that all days are present in your dataset. You can do without it too, but you might skip days in your dataset.

```
SELECT
 d."date"
 , SUM(COALESCE(a.activated::int,0)
   - COALESCE(a2.churned::int,0)
   + COALESCE(a.resurrected::int,0)) OVER w
 , d."date", a."activated", a2."churned", a."resurrected" FROM
 generate_series('2010-01-01'::date, CURRENT_DATE, '1 day'::interval) d
 LEFT OUTER JOIN vw_activity a ON d."date" = a."date"
 LEFT OUTER JOIN vw_activity a2 ON d."date" = (a2."date" + INTERVAL '30 days')::date
 WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY d."date") ORDER BY d."date";
```

You can of course do this in a single query, but this helps understand the structure better.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show us your complete table definition, but maybe something like this:

```
select date,
       count(*) over (partition by date_trunc('day', date) order by date) as dau,
       count(*) over (partition by date_trunc('month', date) order by date) as mau
from sessions
order by date;
```

To get the percentage without repeating the window functions, just wrap this in a derived table:

```
select date, 
       dau,
       mau,
       dau::numeric / (case when mau = 0 then null else mau end) as pct
from (
    select date,
           count(*) over (partition by date_trunc('day', date) order by date) as dau,
           count(*) over (partition by date_trunc('month', date) order by date) as mau
    from sessions
) t
order by date;
```

Here is an example output:

```
postgres=> select * from sessions;
 session_date | user_id
--------------+---------
 2014-05-01   |       1
 2014-05-01   |       2
 2014-05-01   |       3
 2014-05-02   |       1
 2014-05-02   |       2
 2014-05-02   |       3
 2014-05-02   |       4
 2014-05-02   |       5
 2014-06-01   |       1
 2014-06-01   |       2
 2014-06-01   |       3
 2014-06-02   |       1
 2014-06-02   |       2
 2014-06-02   |       3
 2014-06-02   |       4
 2014-06-03   |       1
 2014-06-03   |       2
 2014-06-03   |       3
 2014-06-03   |       4
 2014-06-03   |       5
(20 rows)

postgres=> select session_date,
postgres->        dau,
postgres->        mau,
postgres->        round(dau::numeric / (case when mau = 0 then null else mau end),2) as pct
postgres-> from (
postgres(>     select session_date,
postgres(>            count(*) over (partition by date_trunc('day', session_date) order by session_date) as dau,
postgres(>            count(*) over (partition by date_trunc('month', session_date) order by session_date) as mau
postgres(>     from sessions
postgres(> ) t
postgres-> order by session_date;
 session_date | dau | mau | pct
--------------+-----+-----+------
 2014-05-01   |   3 |   3 | 1.00
 2014-05-01   |   3 |   3 | 1.00
 2014-05-01   |   3 |   3 | 1.00
 2014-05-02   |   5 |   8 | 0.63
 2014-05-02   |   5 |   8 | 0.63
 2014-05-02   |   5 |   8 | 0.63
 2014-05-02   |   5 |   8 | 0.63
 2014-05-02   |   5 |   8 | 0.63
 2014-06-01   |   3 |   3 | 1.00
 2014-06-01   |   3 |   3 | 1.00
 2014-06-01   |   3 |   3 | 1.00
 2014-06-02   |   4 |   7 | 0.57
 2014-06-02   |   4 |   7 | 0.57
 2014-06-02   |   4 |   7 | 0.57
 2014-06-02   |   4 |   7 | 0.57
 2014-06-03   |   5 |  12 | 0.42
 2014-06-03   |   5 |  12 | 0.42
 2014-06-03   |   5 |  12 | 0.42
 2014-06-03   |   5 |  12 | 0.42
 2014-06-03   |   5 |  12 | 0.42
(20 rows)

postgres=>
```

Comment: Looks great - question: is MAU calendar month or the month previous to each day? The ideal is month previous to that day.

Comment: I've run this query and it's not working. The MAU is increasing from 0 at the beginning of the month to the cumulative total of users at the end of the month. Also, the wrapper needs a group by date, dau, mau.

Comment: @DavidBailey: then you need to supply more details - especially the table structure and a bit more sample data. And no, the wrapper does not need a group by as I'm using a window function which generates a cumulative count. Unfortunately SQL Fiddle doesn't work right now, because then I would have supplied a "live" example. I have added a transcript from a psql session to show you my example table.

Comment: Your assumed data structure is spot on :) In the live example, monthly active users is 3 on May 1st, 8 on May 2nd and 3 on June 1st. It's not clear what this represents...

Comment: Well there are three entries in the `sessions` table for May 1st and 5 on May 2nd. So the result shows 3 for DAU on May 1st and 5 on May 2nd, but MAU does a cumulative count which means on May 2nd there are 8 sessions.

Comment: Got you. The thing is my definition of MAU is the number of users active in the previous 30 days, not since the beginning of the month. Get what your doing now and the technique will definitely be useful for other queries. Cheers!

Comment: You need to count distinct too. This doesn't do that and thus won't work.