# How to get DAU / WAU / MAU charts with ElasticSearch and Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

The question is same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33226570/how-to-calculate-dau-mau-with-bigquery-engagement) but about ElasticSearch.

Full question description is [available here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-get-dau-wau-charts-in-elasticsearch/64774).

How to get Weekly Active Users and Monthly Active Users with ElasticSearch and how to show the results on Kibana?

Answer (score 0):

edit: Sorry, SO won't submit this with  tags and I can't get the four spaces approach working, so the JSON is a mess

I've found a way to get this working for me. I'm on 5.1.1, but I believe it is 'supported' on earlier versions too.

1. Create three metric visualisations, one for MAU, one for WAU one for DAU
2. Save them to dashboard, make sure your time filter is >= 1 month and that "Store time with dashboard" is selected
3. Note they will all display the same value
4. Go to Visualisations -> Open -> Manage Visualisations
5. Open each one in turn, the `kibanaSavedObjectMeta.searchSourceJSON` should look something like this (although you may also have something in `"filter" []`)

   {
    "index": "yourindex",
     "query": {
       "query_string": {
         "query": "*",
         "analyze_wildcard": true
       }
     },
     "filter": []
   }
6. Alter it to add the following into `"filter" []`, where `@timestamp' is your timestamp and the value for gt is adjusted for one (d)ay/(w)eek/(M)onth

   {
       "range": {
           "@timestamp": {
               "gt": "now-1d"
           }
       }
   }
7. Go back to the dashboard, values should now reflect the range you specified.

Note 1: The time range from the dashboard is still applied to the visualisation, so selecting a range less than one month will cause the monthly value to be clipped accordingly, and so on with the other values.

Note 2: I haven't seen this documented anywhere, and the kibana visualisation settings pages do have dire warnings about adjusting their settings, so do use this as your own risk.

Comment: Hello, @pjcard. You can find my solution here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-get-dau-wau-charts-in-elasticsearch/64774