# Rolling 7 day uniques & 31 day uniques in BigQuery w/ Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

I'm trying to setup a rolling 7 day users & rolling 31 day users in BigQuery (w/ Firebase) using the following query. I want it where for each day it examines the previous 31 days as well as 7 days. I've been stuck and getting the message:

> LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join.

The query:

```
With events AS (
    SELECT PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", event_date) as event_date, user_pseudo_id FROM `my_data_table.analytics_178206500.events_*`  
    Where _table_suffix NOT LIKE "i%" AND event_name = "user_engagement"
    GROUP BY 1, 2
),
DAU AS (
    SELECT event_date as date, COUNT(DISTINCT(user_pseudo_id)) AS dau
    From events
    GROUP BY 1
)

SELECT DAU.date, DAU.dau,
(
    SELECT count(distinct(user_pseudo_id))
    FROM events
    WHERE events.event_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DAU.date, INTERVAL 29 DAY) and dau.date
) as mau,
(
    SELECT count(distinct(user_pseudo_id))
    FROM events
    WHERE events.event_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DAU.date, INTERVAL 7 DAY) and dau.date
) as wau
FROM DAU
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

I'm able to get the DAU part but the last 7 day users (WAU) & last 31 day users (MAU) aren't coming through. I have tried to CROSS JOIN DAU w/ events but I get the following results [GraphResults](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2VNY.png)

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I think, this might help you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49866033/4878977