# LEFT OUTER JOIN Error creating a subquery on bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, subquery, left-join

I'm trying to eval MAL, WAL and DAU from a event table on my bq...

I create a query find DAU and with him find WAU and MAU, 
but it does not work, i received this error:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join.
```

It's my query

```
WITH dau AS (
  SELECT 
      date, 
      COUNT(DISTINCT(events.device_id)) as DAU_explorer         
  FROM `workspace.event_table` as events
  GROUP BY 1
)

SELECT  
  date, 
  dau, 
  (SELECT 
      COUNT(DISTINCT(device_id))  
     FROM `workspace.event_table` as events
     WHERE events.date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(dau.date, INTERVAL -30 DAY)  AND dau.date
     ) AS mau,
  (SELECT 
      COUNT(DISTINCT(device_id)) as DAU_explorer  
    FROM `workspace.event_table` as events
    WHERE events.date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(dau.date, INTERVAL -7 DAY)  AND dau.date
       ) AS wau
FROM dau
```

Where is my error? Is not possible run subqueries like this on bq?

Comment: @JaimeDrq He already provided the error at top.

Comment: :S thanks, I didn't realize....

Comment: @GabrelVelhoGhellere . . . It is not possible to write queries like this in BigQuery (alas).  And, this error is not easy to work around.

Comment: Thank's @GordonLinoff, you know another way eval this kpi's in sql? Like .rolling(30).sum()  and rolling(7).sum()  in python?

Comment: @GabrielVelhoGhellere . . . These are not rolling sums (that would be a wee bit easier).  These are rolling distinct counts.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/49866033/132438 - does this approach work?

Comment: There's no left join in your code.

Comment: @philipxy there's no visible left join, but BigQuery resolves inline subqueries internally as left joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT DATE(creation_date) date, owner_user_id device_id
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` 
  WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM creation_date)=2017
)

#standardSQL
SELECT DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL i DAY) date_grp
 , COUNT(DISTINCT IF(i<31,device_id,null)) unique_30_day_users
 , COUNT(DISTINCT IF(i<8,device_id,null)) unique_7_day_users
FROM `data`, UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 30)) i
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY date_grp
LIMIT 100
OFFSET 30
```

And if you are looking for a [more efficient solution, try approximate results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49866033/132438).

Comment: Thanks, is very interesting this approach dealing with arrays, i will read more about. Works perfectly thanks.