# Fix the MAU problem while calculating DAU and MAU on Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am using the following query to calculate MAU and DAU, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24494373/querying-dau-mau-over-time-daily) post:

```
WITH dau AS
(
  SELECT TRUNC(created_at) AS created_at,
         COUNT(DISTINCT member_id) AS dau
  FROM table ds
  WHERE ds.created_at BETWEEN '2018-09-03' AND '2018-09-08'
  GROUP BY TRUNC(created_at)
)
SELECT created_at,
       dau,
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT member_id)
        FROM table ds
        WHERE ds.created_at BETWEEN created_at - 29*INTERVAL '1 day' AND created_at) AS mau
FROM dau
ORDER BY created_at
```

I try running this query and get the following results:

```
2018-09-03  12844   3976132
2018-09-04  54236   3976132
2018-09-05  58631   3976132
2018-09-06  59786   3976132
2018-09-07  52317   3976132
2018-09-08  4   3976132
```

It can be clearly seen that the MAU column has repeating values. 
How do I fix this? Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should prefix column names:

```
WITH dau AS
(
  SELECT TRUNC(created_at) AS created_at,
         COUNT(DISTINCT member_id) AS dau
  FROM table ds
  WHERE ds.created_at BETWEEN '2018-09-03' AND '2018-09-08'
  GROUP BY TRUNC(created_at)
)
SELECT created_at,
       dau,
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT member_id)
        FROM table ds
        WHERE ds.created_at 
          BETWEEN dau.created_at - 29*INTERVAL '1 day' AND dau.created_at) AS mau
          -- here
FROM dau
ORDER BY created_at
```

or:

```
SELECT TRUNC(created_at) AS created_at,
     COUNT(DISTINCT member_id) AS dau,
     COUNT(DISTINCT member_id) 
     FILTER(WHERE TRUNC(created_at)>=TRUNC(created_at)-29*INTERVAL '1 day') AS mau
FROM table ds
WHERE ds.created_at BETWEEN '2018-09-03' AND '2018-09-08'
GROUP BY TRUNC(created_at)
ORDER BY created_at
```

Comment: That was a really silly bug on my end. Thanks so much for pointing that out :).

Comment: @Patthebug  Great. Please also check if `FILTER` clause returns the same results