# BigQuery, WAU from DAU

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to calculate WAU from DAU using this link:

[Fix the MAU problem while calculating DAU and MAU on Amazon Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53839230/fix-the-mau-problem-while-calculating-dau-and-mau-on-amazon-redshift)

But the solution in the link works for Redshift. I am trying to do the same thing in BigQuery but its giving me this error:

`LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join`

My code is here:

```
    WITH
    data AS (
      SELECT
        EXTRACT(date FROM active_time) AS active_date,
        COUNT(distinct user_id) AS DAU
      FROM
        abc
      GROUP BY
        active_date )
  SELECT
    active_date,
    DAU,
    (select count(distinct user_id)
    from abc
    where EXTRACT(date FROM abc.active_time) between DATE_SUB(data.active_date, interval 7 day) and data.active_date
    ) as WAU
  from data
```

Could someone pls help? TIA

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to achieve your results (note: It's kind of a mean hack to pass through the left join equality check in BQ, but it does the job):

```
select 
   a.active_date, 
   count(distinct a.user) as dau, 
   array_length(array_agg(distinct b.user)) as wau
from abc a
left join data b on array_length(split(cast(a.active_date as string), '-')) = array_length(split(cast(b.active_date as string), '-'))
and b.active_date between date_sub(a.active_date, interval 1 day) and a.active_date
group by 1
```